# How to change the background of an element with a template in code?

Tags: c#, wpf, templates

So I have a `TextBox` in a form which has a `Template` applied to it (it is global to all textboxes). What I want is to change the background color of certain textboxes, depending on whether there is an invalid entry in it. But I need the change to apply to only the one particular textbox (so I can't change the template)

From code, I want to be able to say:

```
tb.Background = (SolidColorBrush)FindResource("myColor");
```

When I do this currently, nothing happens, and I only assume that it is because there is a template applied to the `TextBox tb`.

Is there a way to do this without making a custom `Template`/`Style` for an incorrect entry? (I need to repeat this process for multiple controls, and I dont want so many styles/templates).

Comment: when you say change the background of an element are you saying you want to change the background color of specific TextBox controls based on a particular condition..?

Answer (score 0):

there are two approaches you can use.
Approach #1

```
textBox1.Background = Brushes.Blue;
textBox1.Foreground = Brushes.Yellow;
```

Approach #2

I take it you are creating the TextBox in xaml? In that case you need to give the text box a name. Then in the code behind you can then set the Background property using a variety of brushes. The simplest of which is the SolidColorBrush:

```
myTextBox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
```

Comment: These don't seem to work....for some reason I can't change the background property..

Comment: this should work.. can you post all related code that you are using also is this WPF..?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing your template, but if your code doesn't work, make sure that your template have this:

```
Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
```

Without this, you can't set the background from outside the template.